# Rails Functional Test With Required Children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing, fixtures

Trying to get this function test to pass:

```
test "should create question" do
  assert_difference('Question.count') do
    post :create, :question => @question.attributes
  end
end
```

But @question has validators that require specific children to be present specifically one topic:

```
  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topic_questions
    has_many :topics, :through => :topic_questions

    validate :has_topic

    def has_topic
      (errors[:base] << "You must have one topic") if (topics.count < 1)
    end
  end
```

How would I 1) build the topic for @question in the test and then 2) pass it to the post method since it wouldnt be passed by the .attributes() function?

Answer (score 1):

```
test "should create question" do
  assert_difference('Question.count') do
    @question.topics<<Topic.new(**set topics required and attribute here )
#or try this line of code 
    @question[:topics]={:name=>"bla bla" ** set attribute here what u need}
    post :create, :question => @question.attributes
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing using the following approach? `post :create, question: {topics: @a_topics_array}`

Answer (score 0):

The test is fine, it's the controller and/or model that needs changing. You haven't shown the contents of the `create` action, but there are basically two ways to do it:

```
@question = Question.new(params[:question])
@question.build_topic(<some_params>)
if @question.save
  # ... etc ...
```

Or, use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic` in the `Question` model and then pass the topic parameters in the params hash. Which method is best depends on your specific circumstances.